# SImple differential equation confusion

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Suppose I have been given the following two relations
$$x \propto y^n$$

$$xdy = Kdx $$

I've been asked to find $K$ in terms of $y$.

I've done this is two ways, but the second way doesn't seem to work, even though it makes sense to me.

METHOD 1 :

Noting that,
$dx \propto ny^{n-1}dy$

Plugging this into our equation : $y^ndy=Kny^{n-1}dy$

This yields : $K=\frac{y}{n}$

This is the correct answer according to the book.

METHOD 2 :

In this method, I wanted to integrate first, and then plug in the relation.

$xdy=Kdx$

or, $y=K\ln(x) + c$

However, since I do not know any boundary conditions, I'm not being able to relate $K$ and $y$. I tried plugging the relation between $x$ and $y$ in this, and I got :

$y=Kn\ln(y)+c$

However, how do I proceed from here? Technically speaking, both of these methods should yield the correct answer, and yet I'm stuck with this second method. Is this purely because integration requires a knowledge of the limits while differentiation doesn't? Or is there something obvious that I'm missing here?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: As you have observed in the first way, $K$ need not be a constant. Thus the integration in the second way is in general wrong.

Comment: You know that $x$ is a function of $y$. So when integrating with respect to $x$ on the right side in method 2, you cannot simply treat $K$ as a constant.